# Gerar aplicação Rails offline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aplicação-web, aplicação-desktop

Tenho uma aplicação Rails bem simples, com apenas um controller e duas actions. Basicamente são páginas com imagens, css, e alguns javascripts. Gostaria de gerar uma versão dessa aplicação que rode totalmente offline, apenas em html, sem a necessidade de instalar ruby ou rails no cliente. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Creio que não exista um jeito automatizado de fazer isso, terá que fazer manualmente. Mas como são só 2 páginas, acho dá pra fazer bem rapidinho com o bom e velho `Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V`

Answer (score 1):

Cara não tem como, prá rodar ruby on rails tem que ter ruby instalado.
Se só html, css e js não tem porque fazer isso em rails faz só as páginas estáticas em html, css e js que roda offline.